# Reducing number of labels on axes in gnuplot

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I have generated the code in gnuplot:

```
set key box bottom right width 2 height 1
set format x "10^{%L}"
set format y "10^{%L}"
set xrange [10**(-4):10**12]
set xtics 10**1
set yrange [10**8:10**31]
set ytics 10**1
set ylabel 'Pressure erg cm^{-3}' font 'Times-Italic,14'
set xlabel 'Density g cm^{-3}' font 'Times-Italic,14'
set logscale x
set logscale y
plot '10.dat' u 1:2 with lines title 'T=1e10',\
     '9.dat' u 1:2 with lines title 'T=1e9',\
     '8.dat' u 1:2 with lines title 'T=1e8',\
     '7.dat' u 1:2 with lines title 'T=1e7',\
     '6.dat' u 1:2 with lines title 'T=1e6',\
     '5.dat' u 1:2 with lines title 'T=1e5'
```

to produce such a graph:
[image]

But, I would like to reduce the number of labels on x and y axis so I can get sth like this:

[image]

Are there some simple ways to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are explicitly setting the tic distances to 10. In the gnuplot console type `help xtics`.
Try the following:

```
set xrange [1e-4:1e12]
set xtics 1e-3, 100
set yrange [1e8:1e31]
set ytics 1e9, 1000
```

**Addition:**

Check `help xtics`. You can place the tics "semi-automatically".

**Code:**

```
### "semi-automatic" tics
reset session

set xrange[1e-4:1e12]
set logscale x
set format x ""
set xtics 10

set yrange[1e8:1e31]
set logscale y
set format y ""
set ytics 10

do for [i=-3:12:2] {
    set xtics add (sprintf("10^{%d}",i) 10**i)
}
do for [i=9:30:3] {
    set ytics add (sprintf("10^{%d}",i) 10**i)
}

plot 1e12*x
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I know it works this way, but it's not what I wanted to achieve. I want to have the same number of ticks as in the original graph, but only to reduce the number of labels.

Comment: Ok, now it's getting more clear. You want to reduce the number of tic labels but at the same time keeping all major and minor tics. Usually, each major tic has a label. For sure, there is a workaround. Wait a minute.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time!